# Need help for a small brute force application (C-Programming)

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to develope a small brute force application in C. As operating system I use Ubuntu 14.04. My CPU is an Intel Core i7-920@2.67GHz(stock).

My question is, how can I use MD5_Init, MD5_Update and MD5_Final with openmp without strange cautious during runtime?

For example my main()-function looks like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <time.h>

const char              LiteralsLower[]   = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const int               NLiteralsLower    = sizeof( LiteralsLower ) - 1;
char                    HexByteHash[16];
time_t                  StartTime, EndTime;

/* Prototypes */
static  void            MD5Hash( const char * );
static  void            BruteForce( const int * restrict, const int * restrict, const char *, const int *, int );

int main()
{
    const char HashAsString[] = "172522ec1028ab781d9dfd17eaca4427"; // 'david'
    const int  *BFOptionSize  = &NLiteralsLower;
    const char *BFOption      = LiteralsLower;
    int        PasswordLength = 6;
    int        StrLength      = strlen( HashAsString );

    for( int i = 0; i < StrLength / 2 ; i++ )
    {
        if( !sscanf( HashAsString + 2 * i, "%02x", ( unsigned int * ) &HexByteHash[i] ) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "FEHLER!!! -> '%s' ist kein Hash-Wert!\n", HashAsString );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    fprintf( stdout, "Hash: %s mit einer Länge von %li Zeichen.\n", HashAsString, strlen( HashAsString ) / 2 );

    /* Timer starten */
    time( &StartTime );

    #pragma omp parallel shared( PasswordLength, BFOptionSize )
    for( int PWLength = 0; PWLength < PasswordLength + 1; ++PWLength )
    {
        /* Array-Größe für FstEntry und LstEntry festlegen */
        int FstEntry[PWLength], LstEntry[PWLength];

        /* Array-Felder mit 0 initialisieren */
        for( int j = 0; j < PWLength; ++j )
            FstEntry[j] = LstEntry[j] = 0;

        #pragma omp for schedule( dynamic )
        for( int i = 0; i < *BFOptionSize; ++i )
        {
            FstEntry[0] = i;
            LstEntry[0] = i + 1;
            BruteForce( FstEntry, LstEntry, BFOption, BFOptionSize, PWLength );
        }
    }

    /* Timer stoppen */
    time( &EndTime );

    puts( "!!! Wort nicht gefunden !!!" );

    printf( "Elapsed time: %ld minutes %ld seconds\n\n", ( EndTime - StartTime ) / 60, ( EndTime - StartTime ) % 60 );

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

I'm not sure but I think that until here everything is okay.

The next code is my bruteforce-function:

```
static void BruteForce( const int * restrict FirstEntry, const int * restrict LastEntry, const char *Letters, const int *NLetters, int PSSWDLength )
{
    char Password[PSSWDLength];
    int  Entry[PSSWDLength + 1];
    int  i, j;

    /* Null-Byte hinzufügen */
    memset( Entry, '\0', PSSWDLength );
    memset( Password, '\0', PSSWDLength );

    /* FirstEntry in Entry kopieren */
    for( i = 0; i < PSSWDLength; ++i )
        Entry[i] = FirstEntry[i];

    i = 0;

    while( i < PSSWDLength )
    {
        /* Generiere Passwort für Hash-Vergleich */
        for( i = 0; i < PSSWDLength; ++i )
            Password[i] = Letters[Entry[i]];

        /* generiertes Wort hashen */
        MD5Hash( Password );

        /* Entry inkrementieren */
        for( i = 0; i < PSSWDLength && ++Entry[PSSWDLength-i-1] == *NLetters; i++ )
            Entry[PSSWDLength-i-1] = 0;

        /* Return wenn Entry != LastEntry raus aus der Schleife */
        for( j = 0; j < PSSWDLength; ++j )
            if( Entry[j] != LastEntry[j] )
                break;

        /* wenn Entry == LastEntry Funktion verlassen */
        if( j == PSSWDLength )
            return;
    }
}
```

At least my hash-function:

```
static void MD5Hash( const char *PasswordStringPointer )
{
    unsigned char Digest[16];

    /* MD5-Hash erzeugen */
    MD5_CTX md5;
    MD5_Init( &md5 );
    MD5_Update( &md5, PasswordStringPointer, strlen( PasswordStringPointer ) );
    MD5_Final( Digest, &md5 );

    if( memcmp( HexByteHash, Digest, 16 ) == 0 )
    {
        printf( "!!! Wort gefunden: '%s' !!!\n", PasswordStringPointer );

        /* Timer stoppen */
        time( &EndTime );

        printf( "Elapsed time: %ld minutes %ld seconds\n\n", ( EndTime - StartTime ) / 60, ( EndTime - StartTime ) % 60 );

        /* Passwortsuche war erfolgreich */
        exit( EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I use all of my eight cores, sometimes if I start the application, it doesn't find the word that is to be search. 
For example: 172522ec1028ab781d9dfd17eaca4427 <-- 'david' <-- the word to search 
For example I say the max. length of the words to generate is 6. So normaly when I start the application I should have this output:

```
Hash: 172522ec1028ab781d9dfd17eaca4427 mit einer Länge von 16 Zeichen.
!!! Wort gefunden: 'david' !!!
Elapsed time: 0 minutes 1 seconds
```

But sometimes it can happens that I have this output instead:

```
Hash: 172522ec1028ab781d9dfd17eaca4427 mit einer Länge von 16 Zeichen.
!!! Wort nicht gefunden !!!
Elapsed time: 0 minutes 14 seconds
```

That means that for what reason ever, it doesn't generate the right hash. So the application runs until 'zzzzzz' was generated. I cannot understand why.

Comment: Excellent first question. Well written and you provided your thoughts and tries about the issue. Next time be sure to translate the german comments for those of us that cant read it (like me :( )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not professional in *openmp*  , but with printing some debugging information, I find that the generated passwords don't have '\0' at the end, they contain characters like: `abrv▒♣▒`, to solve this, just add `Password[PSSWDLength] = '\0';` in line 105. 
to compile use : `gcc my_md5.c -o my_md5 -fopenmp -lcrypto`

OS windows 7 using Cygwin. 
 by replacing *restrict* with *__restrict* 
 using password *azor* instead of *david*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <time.h>

const char              LiteralsLower[]   = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const int               NLiteralsLower    = sizeof( LiteralsLower ) - 1;
char                    HexByteHash[16];
time_t                  StartTime, EndTime;

/* Prototypes */
static  void            MD5Hash( const char * );
static  void            BruteForce( const int * __restrict , const int * __restrict , const char *, const int *, int );
int omp_get_num_threads(void);

int main()
{

    //const char HashAsString[] = "172522ec1028ab781d9dfd17eaca4427"; // 'david'
    const char HashAsString[] = "f68d28e078cc6aa6c163f787da7572eb"; // 'azor'
    const int  *BFOptionSize  = &NLiteralsLower;
    const char *BFOption      = LiteralsLower;
    int        PasswordLength = 6;
    int        StrLength      = strlen( HashAsString );

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < StrLength / 2 ; i++ )
    {
        if( !sscanf( HashAsString + 2 * i, "%02x", ( unsigned int * ) &HexByteHash[i] ) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "FEHLER!!! -> '%s' ist kein Hash-Wert!\n", HashAsString );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    fprintf( stdout, "Hash: %s mit einer L?nge von %li Zeichen.\n", HashAsString, strlen( HashAsString ) / 2 );

    /* Timer starten */
    time( &StartTime );
    int PWLength;

    #pragma omp parallel shared( PasswordLength, BFOptionSize )
    {
    for(PWLength = 0; PWLength < PasswordLength + 1; ++PWLength )
    {
        int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);

        /* Array-Gr??e für FstEntry und LstEntry festlegen */
        int FstEntry[PWLength], LstEntry[PWLength];

        /* Array-Felder mit 0 initialisieren */
        int j ;
        for( j= 0; j < PWLength; ++j )
            FstEntry[j] = LstEntry[j] = 0;

        int i ;
        #pragma omp for schedule( dynamic )
        for( i= 0; i < *BFOptionSize; ++i )
        {
            FstEntry[0] = i;
            LstEntry[0] = i + 1;
            BruteForce( FstEntry, LstEntry, BFOption, BFOptionSize, PWLength );
        }

    }
    }


    /* Timer stoppen */
    time( &EndTime );

    puts( "!!! Wort nicht gefunden !!!" );

    printf( "Elapsed time: %ld minutes %ld seconds\n\n", ( EndTime - StartTime ) / 60, ( EndTime - StartTime ) % 60 );

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
static void BruteForce( const int * __restrict FirstEntry, const int * __restrict  LastEntry, const char *Letters, const int *NLetters, int PSSWDLength )
{
    char Password[PSSWDLength];
    int  Entry[PSSWDLength + 1];
    int  i, j;

    /* Null-Byte hinzufügen */
    memset( Entry, '\0', PSSWDLength );
    memset( Password, '\0', PSSWDLength );

    /* FirstEntry in Entry kopieren */
    for( i = 0; i < PSSWDLength; ++i )
        Entry[i] = FirstEntry[i];

    i = 0;

    while( i < PSSWDLength )
    {
        /* Generiere Passwort für Hash-Vergleich */
        for( i = 0; i < PSSWDLength; ++i )
            Password[i] = Letters[Entry[i]];


        //houssam
        Password[PSSWDLength] = '\0';
        printf("%s    length = %d  %d \n ", Password , PSSWDLength , strlen(Password));

        /* generiertes Wort hashen */
        MD5Hash( Password );

        /* Entry inkrementieren */
        for( i = 0; i < PSSWDLength && ++Entry[PSSWDLength-i-1] == *NLetters; i++ )
            Entry[PSSWDLength-i-1] = 0;

        /* Return wenn Entry != LastEntry raus aus der Schleife */
        for( j = 0; j < PSSWDLength; ++j )
            if( Entry[j] != LastEntry[j] )
                break;

        /* wenn Entry == LastEntry Funktion verlassen */
        if( j == PSSWDLength )
            return;
    }
}
static void MD5Hash( const char *PasswordStringPointer )
{
    unsigned char Digest[16];

    /* MD5-Hash erzeugen */
    MD5_CTX md5;
    MD5_Init( &md5 );
    MD5_Update( &md5, PasswordStringPointer, strlen( PasswordStringPointer ) );
    MD5_Final( Digest, &md5 );

    if( memcmp( HexByteHash, Digest, 16 ) == 0 )
    {
        printf( "!!! Wort gefunden: '%s' !!!\n", PasswordStringPointer );

        /* Timer stoppen */
        time( &EndTime );

        printf( "Elapsed time: %ld minutes %ld seconds\n\n", ( EndTime - StartTime ) / 60, ( EndTime - StartTime ) % 60 );

        /* Passwortsuche war erfolgreich */
        exit( EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello dear Houssam, thank you very very much. You saved my day. You are my hero. :-) Now it work's correctly. 
        Password[PSSWDLength] = '\0'; <-- This did the trick.

Comment: @DaveDexter you should accept the answer, this the local way of saying Thanks.